# Termination for unused pins on motor controller

Tags: circuit-design, motor-controller, termination

I am designing a motherboard for a motor controller.
The motor will be a BLDC motor. I will be using the hall sensor pins on the Motor controller but have no need for several of the features offered by the controller such as the incremental encoders and the digital input and output pins. The question i have is should these be terminated? Also some explanation around the rationale would be appreciated. The datasheet doesn't say what to do with unused pins.

For the digital inputs they are internally pulled down with a 47k. I see no harm in externally terminating with a 10k.

[image]

Should I leave the digital outputs unterminated? Any harm with pulling this down to ground too? Minimise any possibility for noise pick up.
[image]

The encoders can be used as differential or single ended.
I have tied them all to ground with a 10k pull down.

Any guidance or thoughts would be helpful

[image]

Comment: Can you provide  part numbers or datasheet links? screenshots of cherry picked datasheet sections aren't very helpful